# htaccess redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, redirect, parameters

I've been trying to to find a solution using .htaccess to redirect the following urls:

**from:**

```
mydomain.com/my-short-list/1AXC7682 or mydomain.com/my-short-list/1AXC7682/
```

**to:**

```
mydomain.com/my-short-list/?u=1AXC7682
```

**from:**

```
mydomain.com/user-reviews/42 or mydomain.com/user-reviews/42/
```

**to:**

```
mydomain.com/user-reviews/?urid=42
```

and finally:

**from:**

```
mydomain.com/videos/1055687406001/130433/bmw-i8-concept-sports-car-in-detail or  
mydomain.com/videos/1055687406001/130433/bmw-i8-concept-sports-car-in-detail/
```

**to:**

```
mydomain.com/videos/?vid=1055687406001&pid=130433&url=bmw-i8-concept-sports-car-in-detail
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Update your .htaccess with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^my\-short\-list/([0-9]{1}[a-z0-9]{7})/?$ /my-short-list/?u=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user\-reviews/([0-9]+)/?$ /user-reviews/?urid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+) /videos/?vid=$1&pid=$2&url=$3 [NC,L]

#wp default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately, it still not working, please see the comment on Tom Knapen post.

Comment: I see, yes code with wordpress will be different than using this code by itself in the .htaccess file

Comment: These redirections rules are driving me crazy man... Your solution made a lot of sense for me, but it still no working!

Comment: if you remove temporary the wordpress one does it work? (`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` and after)`- just comment then like add the `#` before like: `#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: huh... that's interesting... it did work at all... in fact, the whole website went 404!

Comment: even the link `user-reviews/42` ?

Comment: I am not getting a 404 page with user-reviews/42, but it still not redirecting to the proper page

Comment: is the `user-reviews` folder exists?

Comment: the user-review is working just fine, but the shortlist and video url still not working properly... let me give you a couple of examples... the shortlist u parameters is always 8 digits long, start with a number and all characters are displayed in capital: 7M5Z3G9Y. Now about the video section, after I've implemented your suggestion, the url: /videos/1055687406001/130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail become: /130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail (which is the original article url)

Comment: ok well ([a-z0-9]+) means any char/num and the [NC] means non case so that should work. unless you needs exactly 8 chars starting with a  number (although your example said: mydomain.com/my-short-list/AXC7682) -- for the video i get: `Array ( [vid] => 1055687406001 [pid] => 130433 [url] => bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail ) ` which is correct no? what do you mean it becomes /130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail

Comment: yes man... it's totally right... when I said "it becomes /130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail", it's because if I type the url /videos/1055687406001/130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail the wordpress change it to (and display the content of the url:) 130433/bmw-i8-concept-plug-in-hybrid-sports-car-in-detail

Comment: ok i updated my answer for the `my-short-list` let me know if its working

Comment: when you say it becmes the other url you means it redirects to the url?

Comment: sorry mate, it was that what I meant. About your last update: still the very same problem... It's so weird... the rule for user-reviews (which is working fine) is so similar to my-short-list, I really don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: i don't either, do you have any other rules in the .htaccess? because the video link does not make sense why it redirects just by using these rules

Comment: sorry mate... I was in my lunch break (australia)... about your last question: I am just have your suggestion in my .htaccess file, nothing else! :(

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be the cause, but I set my wordpress (@ mydomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) to use the following link structure: /%post_id%/%postname%/

Comment: i'm not a wordpress expert but it looks like the video link redirect you provided.

Comment: It's all right mate, I will try to figure it out and if I find a solution, I will post here... Anyway... thank you very much for your time / help... I really appreciated that!

Comment: thanks for this, i had dash i forgot to escape and i had to use {1}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^my-short-list/ my-short-list/?u= [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user-reviews/ user-reviews/?urid= [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ videos/?vid=$1&pid=$2&url=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry man,I should be more specific:  
I am using wordpress in my blog, and the current settings for .htaccess is:  
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
# END WordPress  
I've tried to use your and Book Of Zeus solution, but unfortunately, it still not working...